# how to receive data from bluetooth device using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth

I am new to javascript and node.js. Currently am working in medical project. First i will explain my work. I have to receive data from Bluetooth device (normal BP rate ,pulse rate ) and display the readings in the web app using node.js. I don't know how to receive data from Bluetooth device (patient monitor machine) can you guys suggest me some blogs or books to read. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this help [Talk to your Bluetooth device using Node.js](http://opensourceforu.com/2017/02/talk-bluetooth-device-using-node-js/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use "node-bluetooth" to send and receive data from and to a device respectively. This is a sample code:-

```
const bluetooth = require('node-bluetooth');

// create bluetooth device instance

const device = new bluetooth.DeviceINQ();

device
    .on('finished', console.log.bind(console, 'finished'))
    .on('found', function found(address, name) {
        console.log('Found: ' + address + ' with name ' + name);

        device.findSerialPortChannel(address, function(channel) {
            console.log('Found RFCOMM channel for serial port on %s: ', name, channel);

            // make bluetooth connect to remote device
            bluetooth.connect(address, channel, function(err, connection) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                connection.write(new Buffer('Hello!', 'utf-8'));
            });

        });

        // make bluetooth connect to remote device
        bluetooth.connect(address, channel, function(err, connection) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            connection.on('data', (buffer) => {
                console.log('received message:', buffer.toString());
            });

            connection.write(new Buffer('Hello!', 'utf-8'));
        });
    }).inquire();
```

It scans for the device name given in "device" variable.

Comment: Thanks bro its working but I'm having an issue here. It is not showing the available bluetooth devices to pair. It gets connected automatically to the nearby bluetooth devices. Can you help me how to list the bluetooth devices @Asim Raja Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks bro @Asim Raja but its same as before not showing list of bluetooth devices found it just shows one device and tries to pair automatically and after pairing i get an error : bluetooth.connect(address, channel, function(err, connection){
                           ^

ReferenceError: channel is not defined

Comment: hi asim, sello,                                                                                                  
I'm just use the below code, to get the list of available devices but it is throwing error as mentioned below, please guide me

device
    .on('finished', console.log.bind(console, 'finished'))
    .on('found', function found(address, name) {
        console.log('Found: ' + address + ' with name ' + name);
    }).inquire();

Error:
}).inquire(); Error: opening socket.
       ^

Comment: Hey, I'm looking for the package which supports Bluetooth version 5. although I can not be able to install node-bluetooth package as it's giving gyp errors. if you can share how you were able to install the package then that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Try [noble](https://github.com/noble/noble) library. That's how I get information about my Xiaomi Mi Band 3 device:

```
const arrayBufferToHex = require('array-buffer-to-hex')
const noble = require('noble')

const DEVICE_INFORMATION_SERVICE_UUID = '180a'

noble.on('stateChange', state => {
  console.log(`State changed: ${state}`)
  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    noble.startScanning()
  }
})

noble.on('discover', peripheral => {
  console.log(`Found device, name: ${peripheral.advertisement.localName}, uuid: ${peripheral.uuid}`)

  if (peripheral.advertisement.localName === 'Mi Band 3') {
    noble.stopScanning()

    peripheral.on('connect', () => console.log('Device connected'))
    peripheral.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Device disconnected'))

    peripheral.connect(error => {
      peripheral.discoverServices([DEVICE_INFORMATION_SERVICE_UUID], (error, services) => {
        console.log(`Found service, name: ${services[0].name}, uuid: ${services[0].uuid}, type: ${services[0].type}`)

        const service = services[0]

        service.discoverCharacteristics(null, (error, characteristics) => {
          characteristics.forEach(characteristic => {
            console.log(`Found characteristic, name: ${characteristic.name}, uuid: ${characteristic.uuid}, type: ${characteristic.type}, properties: ${characteristic.properties.join(',')}`)
          })

          characteristics.forEach(characteristic => {
            if (characteristic.name === 'System ID' || characteristic.name === 'PnP ID') {
              characteristic.read((error, data) => console.log(`${characteristic.name}: 0x${arrayBufferToHex(data)}`))
            } else {
              characteristic.read((error, data) => console.log(`${characteristic.name}: ${data.toString('ascii')}`))
            }
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **node-ble** a Node.JS library that leverages on D-Bus and avoids C++ bindings.
https://github.com/chrvadala/node-ble

Here a basic example

```js
async function main () {
  const { bluetooth, destroy } = createBluetooth()

  // get bluetooth adapter
  const adapter = await bluetooth.defaultAdapter()
  await adapter.startDiscovery()
  console.log('discovering')

  // get device and connect
  const device = await adapter.waitDevice(TEST_DEVICE)
  console.log('got device', await device.getAddress(), await device.getName())
  await device.connect()
  console.log('connected')

  const gattServer = await device.gatt()

  // read write characteristic
  const service1 = await gattServer.getPrimaryService(TEST_SERVICE)
  const characteristic1 = await service1.getCharacteristic(TEST_CHARACTERISTIC)
  await characteristic1.writeValue(Buffer.from('Hello world'))
  const buffer = await characteristic1.readValue()
  console.log('read', buffer, buffer.toString())

  // subscribe characteristic
  const service2 = await gattServer.getPrimaryService(TEST_NOTIFY_SERVICE)
  const characteristic2 = await service2.getCharacteristic(TEST_NOTIFY_CHARACTERISTIC)
  await characteristic2.startNotifications()
  await new Promise(done => {
    characteristic2.once('valuechanged', buffer => {
      console.log('subscription', buffer)
      done()
    })
  })

  await characteristic2.stopNotifications()
  destroy()
}
```